# Android. Problems with AudioTrack class. Sound sometimes lost

Tags: android, audio, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I have found open source video player for Android, which uses ffmpeg to decode video.
I have some problems with audio, that sometimes plays with jerks, but video picture is shown well. The basic idea of player is that audio and video are decoded in two different streams, and then in the third stream the are passed back, video picture is shown on SurfaceView and video sound is passed in byte array to AudioTrack and then plays. But sometimes sound is lost or playing with jerks. Can anyone give me start point for what to do (some basic concepts). May be I should change buffer size for AudioTrack or add some flags to it. Here is a piece of code, where AudioTrack class is created.

```
private AudioTrack prepareAudioTrack(int sampleRateInHz,
        int numberOfChannels) {

    for (;;) {
        int channelConfig;
        if (numberOfChannels == 1) {
            channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;
        } else if (numberOfChannels == 2) {
            channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO;
        } else if (numberOfChannels == 3) {
            channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_FRONT_CENTER
                    | AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_FRONT_RIGHT
                    | AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_FRONT_LEFT;
        } else if (numberOfChannels == 4) {
            channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_QUAD;
        } else if (numberOfChannels == 5) {
            channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_QUAD
                    | AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_LOW_FREQUENCY;
        } else if (numberOfChannels == 6) {
            channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_5POINT1;
        } else if (numberOfChannels == 8) {
            channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_7POINT1;
        } else {
            channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO;
        }
        try {
            Log.d("MyLog","Creating Audio player");
            int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRateInHz,
                    channelConfig, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRateInHz,
                    channelConfig, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            return audioTrack;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            if (numberOfChannels > 2) {
                numberOfChannels = 2;
            } else if (numberOfChannels > 1) {
                numberOfChannels = 1;
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a piece of native code where sound bytes are written to AudioTrack

```
int player_write_audio(struct DecoderData *decoder_data, JNIEnv *env,
    int64_t pts, uint8_t *data, int data_size, int original_data_size) {
struct Player *player = decoder_data->player;
int stream_no = decoder_data->stream_no;
int err = ERROR_NO_ERROR;
int ret;
AVCodecContext * c = player->input_codec_ctxs[stream_no];
AVStream *stream = player->input_streams[stream_no];
LOGI(10, "player_write_audio Writing audio frame")

jbyteArray samples_byte_array = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, data_size);
if (samples_byte_array == NULL) {
    err = -ERROR_NOT_CREATED_AUDIO_SAMPLE_BYTE_ARRAY;
    goto end;
}

if (pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
    player->audio_clock = av_rescale_q(pts, stream->time_base, AV_TIME_BASE_Q);
    LOGI(9, "player_write_audio - read from pts")
} else {
    int64_t sample_time = original_data_size;
    sample_time *= 1000000ll;
    sample_time /= c->channels;
    sample_time /= c->sample_rate;
    sample_time /= av_get_bytes_per_sample(c->sample_fmt);
    player->audio_clock += sample_time;
    LOGI(9, "player_write_audio - added")
}
enum WaitFuncRet wait_ret = player_wait_for_frame(player,
        player->audio_clock + AUDIO_TIME_ADJUST_US, stream_no);
if (wait_ret == WAIT_FUNC_RET_SKIP) {
    goto end;
}

LOGI(10, "player_write_audio Writing sample data")

jbyte *jni_samples = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, samples_byte_array,
        NULL);
memcpy(jni_samples, data, data_size);
(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, samples_byte_array, jni_samples, 0);

LOGI(10, "player_write_audio playing audio track");
ret = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, player->audio_track,
        player->audio_track_write_method, samples_byte_array, 0, data_size);
jthrowable exc = (*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env);
if (exc) {
    err = -ERROR_PLAYING_AUDIO;
    LOGE(3, "Could not write audio track: reason in exception");
    // TODO maybe release exc
    goto free_local_ref;
}
if (ret < 0) {
    err = -ERROR_PLAYING_AUDIO;
    LOGE(3,
            "Could not write audio track: reason: %d look in AudioTrack.write()", ret);
    goto free_local_ref;
}

free_local_ref:
LOGI(10, "player_write_audio releasing local ref");
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, samples_byte_array);

end: return err;
```

}

I will be  pleased for any help!!!! Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem is for start point of audio data that write to audio player. In PCM data each 2 byte of data create one sample of audio base on little_endian conversion. for correct playing the PCM data samples must be correctly create an write to audio player. If the start point of reading buffer is not the first byte of sample then the samples of audio can not create correctly and sound will be destroyed. In my situation I read samples from file. In some times the start point of reading data from file had been second byte of sample and then the all data that I read from file had been decode uncorrectly. I solve the problem by checking the start point and if the start point is odd number I increase that and change it to even number. 
excuse me for bad english.